# Does Bert-rpc use http?

Tags: bert-rpc

I'm building a low-level, high-performance, cross-platform cloud architecture that needs to utilize a fast rpc system.  I'm considering bert-rpc, but I'm not sure if this uses http or sits directly on top of tcp/ip.  Basically, I care about how many round trips are needed for a single rpc call, and the message delivery guarantees that come with bert-rpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses tcp directly, no http.

Source: email from mojombo.